Preserve Generics while spreading function
How can one preserve the generics of a higher-order function that converts another function with a single argument into its spreaded counterpart?
Here is the problem:
const implementation = (() => {}) as any;

type Spread1 = <A, R>(
  fn: (arg: A) => R
) => {
  (arg: A, ...args: A[]): R[];
  (args: A[]): R[];
};

const spreaded1: Spread1 = implementation;

const result1 = spreaded1(<G extends string>(g: G) => g);
// =>
// {
//  (arg: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown[];
//  (args: unknown[]): unknown[];
// }
// Expected:
// {
//  <G extends string>(arg: G, ...args: G[]): G[]
//  <G extends string>(arg: G[]): G[]
// }

Here I tried the same thing with conditional types:

type Spread2<F> = F extends (arg: infer A) => infer R
  ? { 
    (arg: A, ...args: A[]): R[]; 
    (args: A[]): R[] 
  }
  : never;

const spreaded2 = <F>(fn: F): Spread2<F> => implementation;

const result2 = spreaded2(<G>(g: G) => g);

And here by reassigning previous generics.
type Spread3 = <A, R>(
  fn: (arg: A) => R
) => {
  <A2 extends A, R2 extends R>(arg: A2, ...args: R2[]): R2[];
  <A2 extends A, R2 extends R>(args: A2[]): R2[];
};

const spreaded3: Spread3 = implementation;

const result3_1 = spreaded3(<G>(g: G) => g);
const result3_2 = spreaded3(<G extends string>(g: G) => g);
// => Error:
// Argument of type
//       '<G extends string>(g: G) => G'
//     is not assignable to parameter of type
//       '(arg: unknown) => string'.
//
// Types of parameters 'g' and 'arg' are incompatible.
// Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)


I did end up finding a solution, not sure if its a bug or a feature:
const implementation = (() => {}) as any;

type Spread = <A, R>(
  fn: <_>(arg: A) => R
) => {
  <A0 extends A, R0 extends R>(arg: A0, ...args: A0[]): R0[];
  <A0 extends A, R0 extends R>(args: A0[]): R0[];
};

const spreaded1: Spread = implementation;

const result1 = spreaded1(<G extends string>(g: G) => g);

Would be nice if one could reopen this issue...

What you want is not possible, sorry. TS doesn't support higher order generics except for very specific circumstances as detailed in ms/TS#30215. In particular, your spreaded function doesn't return "a function type with a single call signature", so generics don't propagate. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

Yes I believe you got it right, if "single call signature" is equivalent in meaning to "not overloaded".

See the linked q/a for more information. You could probably refactor to a union of rest tuples like this playground link.

The given playground solution is a perfect workaround for me! Thanks alot!
If you want to give an answer I would love to accept it.
